# Centos genkey command not found

Tags: centos

I'm setting up a mail server as per this tutorial : [http://www.campworld.net/...](http://www.campworld.net/thewiki/pmwiki.php/LinuxServersCentOS/Cent6VirtMailServer)

And have ran into an error when I try to enter this command

```
genkey --days 3650 mail.mydomain.com
-bash: genkey: command not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your PATH, genkey should be found as /usr/bin/genkey so you should ensure that /usr/bin is in your path

```
yum provides */genkey
...
crypto-utils-2.4.1-24.2.el6.x86_64 : SSL certificate and key management
                               : utilities
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/genkey.
```

If your path is good, you can install genkey with

```
yum install crypto-utils
```

Comment: needed `mod_ssl` as well.